# Show $\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\phi(n)^s}}{\zeta(s)}=\prod_{p}(1-1/p^s+1/(p-1)^s)$.

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, totient-function

I want to show that the following equality and that the product is absolutely convergent and uniformally convergent on compact subsets of ${s:Re(s)>1}$.

$$\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\phi(n)^s}}{\zeta(s)}=\prod_{p}(1-\frac{1}{p^s}+\frac{1}{(p-1)^s})$$

The sum above may be expressed as a Dirichlet series, but I don't want to use that. I would like some help on how to solve this problem.

Comment: You can write the sum as a product a'la Euler product.

Comment: Thank you @Wojowu. The solution was that simple.

Comment: For $\Re(z)$ large enough $F(s,z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-z} \phi(n)^{-s} = \prod_p (1+\sum_{k =1}^\infty p^{-zk} \phi(p^k)^{-s})$ and $\frac{F(s,z)}{\zeta(s+z)} = \prod_p (1-p^{-s-z}) (1+\sum_{k =1}^\infty p^{-zk} \phi(p^k)^{-s})$. For what $s,z$ does the latter converge ?